# How to use DateTimeZone in Java

Tags: java, jodatime

I've been trying to convert a server's date and time to user's one with the following code

```
@Test
public void playingWithJodaTime() {

    LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime();
    System.out.println("server localDateTime : "
            + localDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toDate());
    System.out.println("user's localDateTime : "
            + localDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Jakarta"))
                    .toDate());
}
```

Printed result

```
server localDateTime : Tue Dec 17 00:04:29 SGT 2013
user's localDateTime : Tue Dec 17 01:04:29 SGT 2013
```

However the printed result is not like what I expected since the server time zone is `(UTC+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, Singapore` while the user's is `(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta`.

What did I do wrong here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are converting [**DateTime**](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) to java [**Date**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) (why?).
`java.util.Date` uses default JVM's time zone
So, you missed time zone at this conversion.

This example works as expected:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime();
System.out.println("server localDateTime : "
        + localDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault()));
System.out.println("user's localDateTime : "
        + localDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Jakarta")));
```

if you want to convert joda DateTime to something else, then convert it to [**Calendar**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

```
  LocalDateTime localDateTime = new LocalDateTime();
  System.out.println("server localDateTime : "
        + localDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toGregorianCalendar());
  System.out.println("user's localDateTime : "
        + localDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Jakarta")).toGregorianCalendar());
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is the use of toDate(). Why? By saying toDate() you convert your LocalDateTime to a java.util.Date which is timezone-independent. But then you use implicitly the toString()-method on j.u.Date which uses your default timezone, so in both cases you get the same representation.

The solution is just to leave out the call of toDate(). JodaTime objects have better toString()-implementations closely following ISO standard and will print the result in different timezones as you have specified.

Comment: upps - I was too slow. Anyway, I think it is a design weakness in JodaTime api to offer this method toDate(). JSR 310 does not do this.

Comment: The `toDate()` method in Joda-Time is needed as a gateway to interact with old classes that only support java.util.Date. That method is a feature, certainly not a design failure. JSR 310 in Java 8 does indeed do the very same thing except that they put the conversion method on the Date class as a [`from`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) method rather than a `to` method.

Comment: I know the purpose of toDate() as gateway/bridge to old jdk stuff. The difference is where this method should be located, directly in DateTime or better elsewhere? This stackoverflow issue indicates an easy misuse of this "feature". We should try to move users further away from j.u.Date and not to encourage them using it.

Comment: I agree. Clever of the JSR 310 team to move the conversion method to the java.util.Date class for the reason you cite.

Answer (score 1):

A [`LocalDateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html) represents a datetime **without** a time zone.

By calling `toDateTime(DateTimeZone)` you enrich the `LocalDateTime` with the provided timezone to get a [`DateTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) which has the same date and time as the original `LocalDateTime` but is associated with the provided timezone. Note that you do not convert when calling `toDateTime`, because the original local datetime does not have an associated timezone.

On The server :

1. The server local datetime is `Tue Dec 17 00:04:29 2013`.
2. You associate a `UTC+08:00` timezone.
3. With `toDate().toString()` this is converted to a representation in the default timezone  `+08:00` (or `SGT`) which is `Tue Dec 17 00:04:29 SGT 2013`. The conversion is an identity because the associated timezone is `SGT`.

On the user:

1. The user has local datetime `Tue Dec 17 00:04:29 2013`
2. You associate a `UTC+07:00` timezone.
3. With `toDate().toString()` you convert to representation in the default timezone  `+08:00` (or `SGT`) so the time is `Tue Dec 17 01:04:29 SGT 2013`. There is a +1 hour time difference between Singapore and Jakarata and so it is 1 am in Singapore when it's midnight in Jakarta.

Answer (score 0):

For me this code did the job.

```
    DateTime dt =DateTime.now();
    System.out.println(dt);

    dt =DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Jakarta"));
    System.out.println(dt);

    dt =DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
    System.out.println(dt);
```

Where classes are

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.LocalDateTime;
```

Output is :

```
2018-07-17T14:30:51.744+05:30
2018-07-17T16:00:51.829+07:00
2018-07-17T10:00:51.830+01:00
```